# Setting formControl in Angular 2 with boolean value 'true' programmatically is marking form as dirty

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to set boolean value in formControl programmatically. But this is marking form as dirty. Going by Angular docs, "programmatic changes to a control's value will not mark it dirty"
https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#pristine

Code:

```
this.formGroup.get(ruleOutput.attributeKey).setValue(JSONUtils.parseJSON(ruleOutput.attributeValue))
```

FOR FYI, JSONParser Code (Don't think any error here):

```
public static parseJSON(input : any) : any{
    try{
        return JSON.parse(input);
    }catch(Error){
        console.log("Inside JSON Utils: Error while parsing input JSON :");
        console.log(input);
        console.log(Error.toString());
        console.log("Return Empty JSON");
        return JSON.parse("{}");
    }
}
```

Point is after setting the value, form is being marked as dirty.

Please help me in getting to root cause of this.

Comment: if (ruleDataList && ruleDataList.length > 0) {
           ruleDataList[0].ruleOutputList.forEach(
                ruleOutput => {
                    if (DisplayUtils.isKeyDisplayable(ruleOutput.attributeKey, "*")) {
                        this.formGroup.get(ruleOutput.attributeKey).setValue(JSONUtils.parseJSON(ruleOutput.attributeValue)); this.formGroup.get(ruleOutput.attributeKey).markAsPristine;
 }
                }
            )
            this.ruleDataAlreadyExists = true;
        }

Comment: Please create a demo for this, I don't see why this should happen.

Answer (score 1):

This is only true for `getters`, not `setters`. If you look at the source-code of `setValue`, you will see that it does the validation as well and therefore marks the control as dirty, since it has been changed:

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.1.0/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L744

What you could do is maybe, set the form values, and then call `myFrom.markAsPristine()`.

Comment: Yes, for now, I added markAsPristine() explicitly. Another thing is that it is happening only for 'boolean', not other data types.